# Is it the process that cleans itself on termination or the kernel?

Tags: kernel, process, process-management, exit

Recently I found this in a powerpoint presentation:

> When a program is compiled and linked, the linker inserts some extra code in the program. It is this code that calls the *main* function about the same way a user calls "lower functions".
>
> The extra code has two functionalities:
>
> - make sure that the C program runs in the right environment
> - cleanup after succesfull termination

Prior to that I thought that cleanup was kernel's job. What is the right story?

Answer (score 8):

Both the kernel and the C runtime do some of the work.

Some of the things that the C runtime does which the kernel doesn't do: it runs handlers previously registered with `atexit()` and it arranges for the integer return value from `main()` to be returned to the system as if with `exit()`.

Of course in the end the kernel will reap all resources (files, memory) regardless of what userland does or doesn't do.